# No N-dimensional tranpose in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

PyTorch's `torch.transpose` function only transposes 2D inputs. Documentation is [here](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.transpose).

On the other hand, Tensorflow's `tf.transpose` function allows you to transpose a tensor of `N` arbitrary dimensions.

Can someone please explain why PyTorch does not/cannot have N-dimension transpose functionality? Is this due to the dynamic nature of the computation graph construction in PyTorch versus Tensorflow's Define-then-Run paradigm?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's simply called differently in pytorch. [torch.Tensor.permute](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.permute) will allow you to swap dimensions in pytorch like tf.transpose does in TensorFlow.

As an example of how you'd convert a 4D image tensor from NHWC to NCHW (not tested, so might contain bugs):

```
>>> img_nhwc = torch.randn(10, 480, 640, 3)
>>> img_nhwc.size()
torch.Size([10, 480, 640, 3])
>>> img_nchw = img_nhwc.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
>>> img_nchw.size()
torch.Size([10, 3, 480, 640])
```

Comment: It's 2022 and they changed it to [`torch.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.permute.html#torch.permute).

Answer (score 7):

`Einops` supports verbose transpositions for arbitrary number of dimensions:

```py
from einops import rearrange
x  = torch.zeros(10, 3, 100, 100)
y  = rearrange(x, 'b c h w -> b h w c')
x2 = rearrange(y, 'b h w c -> b c h w') # inverse to the first
```

(and the same code works for tensorfow as well)

Comment: einops is a great library and should be used more often for tensor manipulations

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yourTensor.mT`

The [description](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.T) for `.T` (which is now depreciated) can help you better understand what `mT` does.