# Pytorch tensor, how to switch channel position - Runtime error

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have my training dataset as below, where X_train is 3D with 3 channels

Shape of X_Train:  (708, 256, 3)
Shape of Y_Train:  (708, 4)

Then I convert them into a tensor and input into the dataloader:

```
X_train=torch.from_numpy(X_data)
y_train=torch.from_numpy(y_data)
training_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_dataset, batch_size=50, shuffle=False)
```

However when training the model, I get the following error:
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size 24 3 5, expected input[708, 256, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 256 channels instead

I suppose this is due to the position of the channel? In Tensorflow, the channel position is at the end, but in PyTorch the format is "Batch Size x Channel x Height x Width"? So how do I swap the positions in the x_train tensor to match the expected format in the dataloader?

```
class TwoLayerNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TwoLayerNet,self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(3, 3*8, kernel_size=5, stride=1),  
            nn.Sigmoid(),
            nn.AvgPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=0))
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(3*8, 12, kernel_size=5, stride=1),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
            nn.AvgPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride = 0))
        #self.drop_out = nn.Dropout()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(708, 732) 
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(732, 4)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.drop_out(out)
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No N-dimensional tranpose in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841654/no-n-dimensional-tranpose-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [`permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.permute).

```
X_train = torch.rand(708, 256, 3)
X_train = X_train.permute(2, 0, 1)
X_train.shape
# => torch.Size([3, 708, 256])
```

Comment: Thanks it works! But I get this error: RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size 24 3 5, expected input[3, 708, 256] to have 3 channels, but got 708 channels instead

Comment: @NewGirl use `X_train.unsqueeze(0)`, you are missing `batch` dimension.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Btw I also used unsqueeze(0) for y_train,  but for the loss phase, how to I reduce the dimension? I used squeeze(1) but it didnt work

Comment: Since you are doing 1d convolution and there are 708 datapoints, you need to arrange your data to be `(samples, channels, width)`, that is, `(708, 3, 256)`. Use permute. By unsqueezing you are saying that there is only one datapoint, which I guess is not true.